Movie with 3 friends using a time machine constructed by one of them
The movie is about 3 friends where one of them makes a time machine. First  they send the dog then the one who made the machine sends himself and lastly he sends his two friends. They get to the same world but it turns out to be a parallel world and there the cars are free to drive and then he goes to see the hospital where he works in the real world.
Then he goes to visit the woman he loves in the real world and learns that she is his wife in the parallel world and that he died in a war. Then he runs away with a woman. They need to play a game where everyone tries to kill them with baseball and chase them and they escape, build a big time machine and get back to the real world.
Near the end the fat one of the three is sent by the police to the woods since he is fat.  They arrest him and give him an option to go to jail or to move to the forest, and there in the forest he meets more fat people. I think that actor is Nick Lansing or maybe someone that looks like him.
I can't remember the movie's name.

Try this Time Travel movies I've seen Also what year is the movie that you ask for ?

I think the actor Nick Lansing is playing in the movie or maybe someone that looks like him as the fat guy that the police in the parallel world arrest and give him an option to go to jail or ot move to the forest and there in the forest he meet more fat ppls .

Please add as many details as possible (approximate year, country\language, where did you see it etc.) from your original account. I think I know what you're after, but I need to make sure.

Walt tell me what do you think about. I can tell that in the movie the main actor is going to the hospital where he is working in the real world but in the parallel world the ppl there get some surgery and then he run away and with a woman they need to play a game where everyone try to kill them with baseball and anything else and chase them and they escape build a big time machine and get back to the real world.

@DanielLip Are you the person who asked the question? If so, please use your original account ('chocolate') and use the edit feature to add these details...

Is it really a time machine, sounds more like a teleporter thing?

I might as well answer this question before I forget as the OP provided more than enough plot details: You're looking for Tempting Fate from 1998 with Tate Donovan. From an IMDb review:

A brilliant scientist is disregarded by the scientific community as harebrained and foolish. He manages to develop a machine that transfers a living being to a parallel universe, a universe that exists "between atoms" or the space within matter, where life is seemingly perfect in every way. His friends get in on the action and in a show of self-centered behavior, make an attempt to stay in the parallel universe and never go back home. It is at this point that the movie's psychological elements begin, as signs of the new world's demons and imperfections begin to take shape.

Everything you mentioned is there. They test the machine on a dog first; The main protagonist goes to the hospital that he worked in and finds out that his parallel world self died in a war; people are free to drive whichever car they find on the street; there's a brutal game where people are hunted and beaten with baseball bats; and the heavy-set guy in the group (Abraham "Kube" Benrubi) is exiled to the park to live with the other heavy-set people.
The entire film is on Youtube. Here's a (Russian dubbed) clip demosntrating how the machine works:



